# What is the console command to skip quests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know you can skip a quest by using CompleteQuest  but that doesn't work for me.
It will go away from my quest tab but still be on the map, and I can't continue.

Is there another way to skip a quest?

Answer (score 2):

You can run this command:

> setstage [quest ID] [stage #]

You can find quest IDs and stage numbers [here at UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quests).

Usually, stage 200 is the end of a quest; so can just write `setstage [quest ID] 200` to mark a quest as completed.

Comment: thanks for the help, but still, I tried the quest Bleak falls barrow and it still doesnt work, I even gave myself the dragonstone, what should I do?

Comment: @AVE I went to your link but I don't see any stage codes. I can't seem to finish Regain Eastmarch. Does anyone know where the quest codes are now or know the code for this task?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is over a year late, but you can skip it via entering...

```
setstage mq103 190
```

That should skip it without fail. you may have to wait a bit for the whole watchtower dragon incident to start, but it otherwise works without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

For the *Bleak Falls Barrow* quest:

```
setstage MQ103 10
setstage MQ103 50
setstage MQ103 180
setstage MQ103 190
```

Put that in commands. If that doesn't work perhaps the Golden Claw quest is interfering. There is no '200' for Bleak Falls Barrow.