# How do I find Severio Pelagia in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I did the Stormcloaks Quest first before I did the Companions Quest so now I can't find Severio Pelagia to do the Quest for the Companions. If there is no way to find him is there a way to get through that mission without finding him, or did I completely screw up the Companions Quest?

Comment: Could the downvoter(s) please explain the downvotes - this question seems quite acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [quest page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Hired_Muscle) you can complete this by:

> To fix this, go to Whiterun, then find [Amren](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Amren) and kill him. At this point the quest line should open back up.

If this doesn't help reloading an old save before the quest will probably fix it because the NPC is randomly selected.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Severio Pelagia's](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Severio_Pelagia) wiki, it is possible you will not be able to fully complete the Companions quest line if you completed the Civil War quest line first.

> His death is inevitable, regardless of the Dragonborn's civil war affiliation, as his home is utterly destroyed during the catapult barrage on the city in the Battle for Whiterun. **Completing the Battle for Whiterun quest or killing him manually could cause the Companions questline as well as Shalidors Writings (Ysgramor) to be incompletable, should they be attempted after his death**

Severio Pelagia is an NPC that is randomly selected during the [Hired Muscle](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Hired_Muscle) quest, but his death would prevent you from getting past this part of the quest line.

Comment: Thanks but is there anyway to skip past that quest

Comment: @CollinRushing If you are on PC, you can use the [Console Command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244632/what-is-the-console-command-to-skip-quests)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not I'm on Xbox 360

Comment: @CollinRushing: If playing Special Edition, there might be a mod or two that can fix this, but I don't know of any off the top of my head.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how Severio Pelagia is related to the Companions and the only thing I can think of is the Giant battle when you first approach his farm, however this doesn't affect you talking to Kodlack Whitemane and joining the Companions. What quest in particular isn't working here?

Comment: @KallumTanton I was mistaken on being unable to start the quest. I edited my answer to clarify that

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. @CollinRushing do you have a save from before starting the Hired Muscle quest? If so you can go back to that and reinitialise the quest to get a different target.